# How to link block and view to basic page

Tags: views, blocks

Please tell me how to link a block and view with to a basic page.

for example I want to add a block for featured service and assign with view, my problem is how to assign with a basic page.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, do you mean you have built a block with views and now you want to create a link inside it to a basic page? or you want the block to shown in specific page?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a view and/or block to a basic page in `structure > blocks`. You can add both view and block to the page.